# How can i split dates into 15 days intervals in a month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sample data set like this :

```
CREATE TABLE Data
(
   Start DATETIME,
   EndDt DATETIME,
   Amount INT
)
GO

--Insert Data

INSERT INTO Data(Start,EndDt,Amount)
VALUES
('14-Apr-14','13-May-14',200),
('15-May-14','16-Jun-14',320)
```

Sample Input :

```
Start        End       Amount
14-Apr-14   13-May-14   200
15-May-14   16-Jun-14   320
```

Sample Output :

```
Start        End       Amount
14-Apr-14   30-Apr-14   100
01-May-14   13-May-14   100
15-May-14   31-May-14   160
01-Jun-14   16-Jun-14   160
```

can anyone suggest on this?

Comment: What should be the logic behind division?

Comment: What you want exactly Di you wanna split month to divide 2 15 15 days ?

Comment: What is the minimum and maximum difference of days between Start and end , I am asking what if the start = `01-jan-2019` and end=`15-feb-2019` then what is the output?

Comment: What have you tried to get the answer yourself as well?

Comment: not exactly 15 days start date is 13th April and end date is 13th may then it should give output like 13th  Apr to 30th Apr and 1st MAY to 13th MAY

Comment: @Larnu I don't have any clue how to achieve this and I'm doing my bit from my side and mean while i hope SO will give something more efficient solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I have tried this code on your table and it is giving desired output

```
select start as dd,'start' as type,amount/2 as amount from data
union all
select enddt as dd,'end' as type,amount/2 as amount from data

select case when type = 'start' then dd--DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, dd), 0)
else DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, dd), 0) end
as start,case when type = 'start' then  DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, dd) + 1, 0))
else dd end as [end],amount
from (select start as dd,'start' as type,amount/2 as amount from data
union all
select enddt as dd,'end' as type,amount/2 as amount from data) a
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution works, but *assumes* you have an ID column on your table. I create a Tally table to be able to generate the date ranges (which in in sets of 16 days, not 15), and then finally get a count in the group and divide `Amount` by it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Data] (ID int IDENTITY,
                         [Start] date,
                         EndDt date,
                         Amount int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.[Data] ([Start],
                        EndDt,
                        Amount)
VALUES ('14-Apr-14', '13-May-14', 200),
       ('15-May-14', '16-Jun-14', 320);
GO
--Create a Tally 
WITH N AS
    (SELECT N
     FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N (N) ),
Tally AS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
     FROM N N1,
          N N2,
          N N3), --1000 rows, more than enough
--Create the dates
Dates AS(
    SELECT D.ID,
           DATEADD(DAY, (T.I - 1) * 16, D.[Start]) AS [Start],
           DATEADD(DAY, T.I * 16, D.[Start]) AS Enddt,
           D.EndDt AS FinalDate,
           D.Amount
    FROM dbo.[Data] D
         CROSS JOIN Tally T
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, (T.I - 1) * 16, D.[Start]) < D.EndDt)
--Final result set
SELECT D.ID,
       LAG(DATEADD(DAY,1,D.Enddt),1,D.[Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY D.ID ORDER BY D.[Start]) AS [Start],
       CASE WHEN D.Enddt > D.FinalDate THEN D.FinalDate ELSE D.Enddt END AS EndDt,
       D.Amount / COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS Amount
FROM Dates D
ORDER BY ID, [Start];
```

[DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4cc6f26103268d6c433ba94baa749c67)

Comment: @Larnu Resultset row 2 is: 1 2014-04-30 2014-05-13 100

Comment: Fixed, @AlexK .

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query:

```
select Start a, last_day(Start) b, amount/2 c from Data
union
select  trunc(EndDt , 'MM') a, EndDt  b, amount/2 c from Data;
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/065n6.png)

Comment: `trunc` isn't a T-SQL function